# Who Owns the Source Code & IP - Developer or Employer?

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, legal, usa, programmer

Imagine you hire someone on a freelancing site to code a (highly) custom website or app with very specific functionality. After they complete the job, you pay them for their work and they hand over the source code to you. Who owns the code / IP? You or the developer? Let's assume the employer resides in the U.S and the freelancer resides in India or another 3rd world country.

I've checked [this question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/4181/25873) and it seems that unless a contract was written explicitly stating that the Freelancer hands over all IP + code to the employer the code may actually "belong" to the Freelancer and the employer is merely able to "use it".

Does this means the Freelancer can re-use the entire code base and unveil an exact replica of your site with the intention to undercut you if he or she chooses? Or does it mean the Freelancer gets to re-use bits and pieces of code for another project?

Thanks

Comment: This s not a support channel for freelance crowd sourcing sites. If you have a question about such a site, you need to ask *them* or review their terms of service.

Comment: @Scott How is the question different than: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/what-to-do-with-code-after-odesk-job-completion

Comment: **6 years** of site growth and changes. **Often** with stack sites, what is acceptable at one time becomes untenable. If questions regarding crowd source sites were allowed here they would quickly take over the entire stack.

Comment: @Scott I see. What if I just leave this part of the question: "So this means the Freelancer can unveil an exact replica of your site to compete with you if he so wishes" and remove the Freelancer.com part. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Sure.. remove **all** aspects referring to crowd sourcing sites.

Comment: @Scott OK updated the question hope it is good now

Comment: Better `:)` Thanks for the consideration.

Answer (score 5):

In **any** creative venture, be it artwork, fiction writing, markup writing, coding, music, film.... the "work" is copyrighted and *owned* by the creator the *moment* it is created.

There are only 9 ways the author "loses" rights to the work. [William Fisher, of Harvard Law, has an excellent lecture on copyrights](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/people/tfisher/Copyright_Lectures_2013.htm). Specifically [Lecture 5 part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-2qLmmDBnE) explains the 9 instances where authors do *not* retain the rights. There is a 10th... if you are an employee or otherwise under a work-for-hire agreement. And an 11th.. if the author gives them away.

So, to that end.. **Yes** the freelancer owns their creation and can do with it what they want.

**Ethical** freelancers aren't going to reuse something in whole. It's not uncommon to pull a part form here or there to flesh out something new, but direct duplication is often something *most* ethical freelancers aren't interesting in doing.

If you fear replication of something you've paid for, a simple solution is to **have a contract** which transfers partial or all rights of the product from the author to the client/buyer. Most freelancers are more than willing to enter such agreements, however costs may be higher given this factor. Barring such an agreement, the author is free to use the work in any manner they see fit, even if it upsets or bothers the client who paid for the work initially.

---

It should be noted that **freelancers** *do not* have an "employer". Freelancers have *clients*, not "employers".

- Employers tell workers **when** to work, **how** to work, **what** to work on, **provide** **tools** for completion of that work, etc.
- Freelancers define their **own hours**, **how** a project is completed, **what projects** they will work on, and use their ***own tools*** to complete those projects.

Definitions matter.

Simply because someone pays me to complete something does *not* make them my "employer", much the same way if I were to hire a plumber to fix my drains, that would not make the plumber my "employee".

The employee <> employer relationship is **always** a work-for-hire arrangement and the employer owns everything created by the employee.

Independent contracting is *often* a freelance position. However, there can be contracts defining ownership which can equate to a more work-for-hire agreement in which the contractor (client) owns everything created by the contractee (worker).

Comment: What if the employer played a big role in shaping the function, vision, direction and success of the entire program - wouldn't that give the employer a good chunk of the IP? I mean software isn't written in a vacuum.. It's not like asking someone to write a book and then sitting back on the couch until the guy finishes his work.. it's like someone who plays an active and critical role in character / story development.. are you so sure that in this case the guy who writes the book (or software) owns the whole IP?

Comment: @S.O.S input, suggestions, ideas, feature requests are all not "when", "what", and "how" to work... Of course a client must provide some direction, but the idea or desire alone does not constitute ownership. One **cannot** copyright any *idea*. It's only the *implementation* of an idea which can be copyrighted and owned.

Comment: Hire me to paint a picture of a turtle... sure it's your idea... but I do the painting on my time, with my tools.. and it's *my* artwork. I can then choose to either sell you the rights to the artwork or not. But you don't own *anything* other than what I'm willing to sell you - which may be merely *usage* rights, not ownership.

Comment: A good example of all this is Zuckerbrg and Facebook... He took an idea from someone else, built it with their input along the way, then decided to keep it. Sure there were legal settlements later (but no definitive wrongdoing on Zuckerberg's part). Ultimately, who owns Facebook now?

Comment: 1) According to ndtv.com the twins accused Mark Zuckerberg of "intellectual property theft", saying he "illegally used source code intended for the website he was hired to create."

"Mark Zuckerberg, who said he hadn't used a single code meant for Harvard Connection in Facebook, finally had to agree to an out of court settlement."

Comment: 2) (continued) It seems your comparison to FB is misconstrued. Mr. Zuckerberg argued that he did NOT use even a "single line" of code that was intended for the website he was hired to create. Even in this case the twins recieved some settlement (albeit insignificant). Now imagine the opposite scenrio: Suppose mark had handed over the entire source code to the twins (after receiving payment) and the twins launched FB (not Mark). A few months later (perhaps after seeing the succes of the website) Mark decides to launch an exact replica of the site (or sell it to someone else who does)

Comment: 3) (continued) I'm pretty certain the outcome would have been very different. I think you're comparing apples to oranges. Moreover, in the example I gave there's clear proof of communication/direction between the "employer" the developer for each step of the way - which clearly shaped the direction and essence of the site. This is the opposite of the winklevoss twins case against Zuckerberg.

Comment: 4) (continued) A NY Times article put it like this "But instead of following through on the verbal agreement, Mr. Zuckerberg delayed work on Harvard Connection and instead worked on his own project. When pressed for answers, he stalled, according to the Winklevosses". It is clear that at some point (early on in the development) Mark decided to go his own way and work on "his own project". Once again,  I think the example I gave is probably the exact opposite of what happened in Zuckerberg's case

Comment: A settlement is **not** an admission of guilt. The settlement was.. in all likelihood... to simply get rid of the issue rather than spend years in the courts. I knew you may bring up the settlement, but in a legal sense.. a settlement merely means "I'll pay you to go away" not "I'm guilty". It's not my intention to argue the merits of the Facebook lawsuit. Point is Zuckerberg created it, he owned it.. sure other's argued that point... but does he not still own it?

Comment: My main point was not the settlement issue (as I said in my comment it was a relatively insignificant amount). My point was that **1)** If you look at the way the NY Times portrayed it, the crux of Mr. Zuckerberg argument was that he was NOT working for the Winklevosse. True, they hired him but he backed out pretty early on. It would be a completely different story had Mark delivered the entire source code of FB to the twins and **then** launched an identical site   2) As ndtv.com put it Zuckerberg  argued that he did not use a "single line of code" that he wrote for..

Comment: (cont) the Winklevosses. In my example, the entire code base is being used. I think you are oversimplifying the link.

Answer (score 1):

Several answers here assume US law. The OP asked specifically about international law. (I am not an expert in international law.)

A better way of looking at this situation is to ask how enforceable are any rights?

In the US, contracts and rights to software realistically have power to the extent that you are willing to go to court to protect them. If you can't afford to sue to protect copyright or violations of the contract, the rights and contract are gone. Years ago, my lawyer told me to walk away from any dispute where I couldn't get back at least $20K (that figure is higher now) because that is how much he would charge me to do such a suit.

In this situation, the OP asked about someone in another country. How enforceable is any contract or "rights to IP" in another country? It is common knowledge to hardware designers that doing business in or having hardware built in certain countries means that someone in that country will copy the design. This is true even though contracts have been signed to prevent such.

In this case, how willing is the OP to go to that country to file a suit? Would the OP win? And if one wins the suit, how much could one realistically get from that person? If the person being sued has a net worth less than $10,000, what would be the value of doing all that effort? It would cost far more than you could get back.

So, we do best to find ethical people to do business with, trust they will honor your IP, and verify by smaller projects that they actually will.

Answer (score 0):

Yes unless a contract is written and payment fulfilled. Anything that freelancer creates belongs to the freelancer not the buyer.

This is one big legal difference to freelancing and employment.

Yes without a contract the freelancers are legally entitled to sell the code (it’s not yours) to anybody else.